# Deleting rows in CSV, if a field partially matches with another

Tags: python, csv

I want to delete a row in a CSV file, if a field partially matches with others.

For example:

```
serial       book name                     author     

1.          Ramakrishna Kathamrita Vol1     Sri M     
2.          Ramakrishna Kathamrita Vol2     Sri M     
3.          Ramakrishna Kathamrita Vol3     Sri M
```

I would like to have only one entry for these three. It should return only:

```
serial       book name          author  

 1.          Ramakrishna Kathamrita Vol1     Sri M
```

Is there any way we can do this in Python?

**EDIT:
(29-12-2017 17:05)**

Sorry for being unclear.

We may set the following criteria.

1. If the book name has `n` words, at least the first`n-1` words should match.
2. If `1.` is satisfied, it will delete the row upon asking the user.

The idea is grossly this:

```
my_string1 = "Ramakrishna Kathamrita Vol1"
my_string2 = "Ramakrishna Kathamrita Vol2"    

splitted1 = my_string1.split()
splitted2 = my_string2.split()

if(splitted1[0] = splitted2[0] & splitted1[1] = splitted2[1])
     then ask the user whether to delete the row;wait for 'y/n'
```

We may also get the word count:

```
def word_count(string):
    tokens = string.split()
    n_tokens = len(tokens)
    return n_tokens
```

Now how do we achieve it 1) **for a CSV** 2)**delete the rows upon asking**?

Comment: What is the criteria for "partially matches"? Once you can define that you can group the CSV rows and combine them as required using a dictionary (or `collections.defaultdict`) or use `itertools.groupby()`.

Comment: Edited. Hope the question is now clear.

Answer (score 0):

> if a field partially matches with others.

You could use a string distance algorithm. [StringDist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/StringDist) module might be useful though you will need to define what's your `similarity` criteria.

Comment: Edited the question. I was looking for something different.

Comment: Then you are close, use `split()` to count words, regex works too. use `word1.rsplit(None, 1)[0] == word2.rsplit(None, 1)[0]` to compare by `n-1` words. Loop through the data but sort it first by book name, then compare the previous book name with the current book name.